# Can evidence produced in a civil action be excluded from a criminal trial?

Tags: criminal-law, civil-law, trial

Following [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4510/10), which is part of a chain of interesting posts exploring the use of civil actions to force liability insurers to pay for unintentional torts of their insureds:  Suppose a person wishes to *lose* a lawsuit for "wrongful death" in order to benefit some third party (e.g., the kids orphaned by an accident in which the policyholder was involved but not charged with any crime).

The person *wants* to establish liability for wrongful death, but *does not want* to risk a charge and conviction for the crime associated with that tort: involuntary manslaughter.

Can the civil trial be conducted in such a way that any concessions or evidence supporting the wrongful death verdict cannot be used against the person in a criminal trial, should at any later time a prosecutor decide to pursue the charge of involuntary manslaughter?

Are there any reliable means of presenting testimony at a civil trial that allow it to be excluded, refuted, or disclaimed in a criminal trial (without committing perjury)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I see the difference in this question from the original one; the only difference appears to be asking for explicit advice of what one must do in the exact set of circumstances (as opposed to a more passive original question), which, IIRC, appears to be offtopic, as this is basically asking specific legal advice.

Comment: @cnst - I don't quite follow: Are you saying *this* question appears to be asking for specific legal advice?  If so: I picked a "strong" hypothetical to illustrate the titular question (and to relate it to the "inspiring" Q&A), but the hypothetical could be *any* tort with a potentially associated crime.  As for differences between the two: This focuses on what theoretical mechanisms exist to avoid what was suggested in the title of the "inspiring" question.

Comment: @feetwet, I'm confused when you say "sue themselves for wrongful death". Is that what you intended to say?

Comment: @gracey209 - Basically, yes: IIRC the original idea is that a couple gets in a car accident.  Passenger dies.  Driver has liability insurance, and is also beneficiary of Passenger's estate.  Driver, as representative of Passenger's estate, wants to sue Driver (self) for wrongful death, thereby compelling Driver's insurance to pay out to Passenger's estate, whose beneficiary is (tada!) Driver.

Comment: OK, you cannot sue yourself.

Comment: Somebody else could be appointed  executor of the estate, and Sue you on behalf of the state though

Comment: @gracey209 - Check the linked question: At least in Utah you can sue yourself as defendant in your capacity as the executor of the estate (as plaintiff)!  Otherwise, sure, let us imagine that if necessary one would find a sympathetic executor to stand as plaintiff.  The point is that, thanks to insurance, there are incentives for defendants to throw civil cases, but *not if they could implicate themselves criminally*.  So this question is: Can that be done?

Comment: Well, even if the court will let the executor sue the "plaintiff" who is all one person, there is nothing to be gained. The insurance won't indemnify and defend. All insurance policies have a clause that say you can only file suit against your own policy under UM/UIM. The general liability provisions won't cover her. So even though she can bring suit against herself, there is nothing to be gained.

Comment: UM/UIM is uninsured/underinsured motorist coverage. So if someone hits you and doesn't have insurance, or if they only have 50k liability and you have 300k, you can bring suit against your own policy for the remaining 250k, with an offset. That's the only way you can sue your own policy. Otherwise, every moron out there would crash their 500$ car into a tree and sue themselves for whiplash!

Comment: @gracey209 - Right; I would assume this strategy would be used for claims under an umbrella liability policy.  Or, [in another case cited](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/4476/10), homeowner liability coverage.

Comment: I read policies all day long and I've never seen one that would allow this.... And my JOB is finding extra coverage....my guess is that it ends up getting appealed again to the state Supreme Court, where it'll be overturned. It's ludicrous

Comment: @gracey209 - Presumably this would have to be an explicit exclusion -- something along the lines of, "We will not make liability payments that inure to the benefit of the insured?"  A quote of such a clause and/or an explanation of why liability insurance won't pay in this manner would be a very helpful answer to this question!

Comment: Ya, almost all policies say something to the effect of "in the event you are negligent that is the proximate cause of injury, or to the detriment of *another person*." Then there are exclusions including the policy holder, anyone who lives with the holder not listed on the policy. Also, the definitions will define ambiguous terms. Like "litigant" is any person other than the tortfeasor under any title or entity affiliation, blah blah blah.

Comment: There is also the terminology that you need to assist in the defense and you have no say regarding settlement so long as it won't find you negligent. You cannot sue and assist, and in the disclosures if you breach that duty to mitigate their losses, your SOL. Also, no jury would like someone who killed someone trying to benefit, if hypothetically they were not excluded from recovery under ins.

Comment: @gracey209 - Ah ha, that would explain why "suing yourself" is not going to work.  Let me rephrase the question so that the plaintiff doesn't fall under those exclusions.  E.g., maybe I was involved in a fatal accident, and even though I'm not being prosecuted for manslaughter I really feel bad for the victim's family, who is eyeing my liability insurance.  So I might say, "Yeah, my insurer will probably drop me, but these people just lost their father.  Losing my current insurance is a small price to pay for his kids getting $1MM."  But I don't want any possibility of criminal blowback.

Comment: People do it all the time; they admit liability when the demand is within policy limits. The ins can't prevent you from testifying truthfully. Usually they will scare clients into denying the claim by telling them that their personal assets could be exposed. It's true... They could, which is why most people will fight it, but if you have adequate coverage orbits not a concern, you can testify as you please.

Comment: This brings up a big issue pertaining to the ethics of insurance lawyers. They have a duty to defend and indemnify (up to your policy limits), but that lawyer is not supposed to be protecting the insurance company – the client is the tortfeasor. However, that's not always how they act in their representation or recommendations.

Comment: @gracey209 - That sounds like a good start to answering this question as clarified.  And we should take your earlier explanation and work it into your answer to the previous question.  I'll take a shot at the latter and you can rollback or refine when you have time.

Comment: Sounds like a plan....